# How to show a Kivy GUI using cron planner?

Tags: python, cron, kivy

I've made a simple Python script that would display a little alert window. I wanted it to do so every 20 minutes, so I looked into the `cron` planner, as I am using Ubuntu.
The command I used to run the script was `python3 alert.py`, with `alert.py` being the script in my home directory.
The `cron` setup was done using the `gnome-schedule` app, so I assume nothing is wrong there.
This is `alert.py`:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (200, 100)
runTouchApp(Label(text = "Test Alert!"))
```

The problem is that the window is not appearing. And as it seems, the script is not running at all (I've added a `os.mkdir` call, but no directories appeared). What's the problem? And how can I see the log that the script outputs to `stdout`?

Comment: I suspect your cron may be not having env set up (including PATH) so that command errors out. Could you please try redirecting the output to a file and see if that has any clues? (you can do so by appending `>>/var/log/mycron.log 2>&1`)

Comment: Also do you see an entry in `crontab -l`?

Comment: Just found similar thing answered which has awesome checklist, please give it a try http://askubuntu.com/questions/15255/cron-jobs-show-up-in-gnome-scheduler-but-dont-execute

Comment: @Ivan thanks, I managed to find a solution in a different way. Yes, `cron` was set up and running (when I tried a shell script, it worked just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the command behaviour to `X application` (rather than `Default behaviour`). After that change, the console shows up and the GUI is displayed.

[image: gnome-schedule]